# Apache modrewrite htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have tried every variation I can find (found examples on Stack Overflow and elsewhere but they don't work for my situation either).

Here is my revised .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
RewriteEngine On

# New Try - apparently does nothing
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?fubar\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/?snafu\/?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://snafu.com/%1 [R,L]

# First try - apparently does nothing
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?fubar\.com
RewriteRule ^\/?snafu\/?(.*)$ https://snafu.com/$1 [R,L]

# this works as expected
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?fubar\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.fubar.com/$1 [R,L]
```

I show above the two ways I have tried to cause 
    http://www.fubar.com/snafu 
to redirect to 
    http://snafu.com

Neither paragraph does anything.

The last paragraph in the file works as expected, so I know that Apache
is doing it's thing properly.

Clearly the file is working in some cases, but I cannot figure out what is going wrong for the other cases.

As suggested, I replaced all my code above with:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
Redirect 301 /snafu https://snafu.com
```

When I try to browse to http://www.fubar.com/snafu/index.html

I get the Firefox message: The page isn’t redirecting properly
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

However, the browser URL window displays the desired destination https://snafu.com/index.html

Chrome reports: The snafu.com page isn’t working
snafu.com redirected you too many times.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Again, the browser URL window displays the desired destination https://snafu.com/index.html

Internet Explorer says: Not Found
The requested URL /snafu.com/index.html was not found on this server.

Opera says: The snafu.com page isn’t working snafu.com redirected you too many times.

Safari says: Safari can't open the page "https://snafu.com/index.html" because Safari can't establish a secure connection to the server "snafu.com"

I don't know if this is important, but both fubar.com and snafu.com have the same IP address - if I clear the browser cache I can directly navigate to https://snafu.com/index.html without problem, so again it appears that Apache is doing its thing properly.

The snafu.com root directory contains the .htaccess file below, which appears to work as expected:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?snafu.fubar\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://snafu.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?snafu\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://snafu.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Removing this file does not change any of the browser behaviors.

My tentative conclusion is that the simple Redirect 301 /snafu https://snafu.com command is confused because both snafu and fubar have the same IP address.  But the ModRewrite should be smarter - I am just not smart enough to come up with the right incantation.

Where am I going wrong?  My goal is to make all existing links that reference fubar.com/snafu to be redirected to snafu.com so that search engines are not confused by two different ways to access the same content.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add this in your htaccess

```
Redirect 301 /snafu http://snafu.com
```